# How to display a text that is in a variable in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to display the value that is stored in the variable
`$('#view-property .imo_desc_site').html(`${property.imo_desc_site}`);`

In my textarea, but I'm not getting it.

What could I be doing wrong?

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="imo_desc_site" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">DESCRIÇÃO DO IMÓVEL - EM BREVE</label>
                                    <textarea readonly rows="15" class="form-control no-resize" style="border: 1px solid #7777774a; border-radius: 10px;">
                                        <span class="imo_desc_site">
                                    </textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: invalid markup, a textarea is no place for a span (which is not even closed)

Comment: Hello, in the other codes of my application, it works perfectly, except in the textarea.

Comment: Hello, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back to edit your question.

Comment: Was my question not clear?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you're trying to add some default text in a textarea, to achieve that, you don't need a span nested inside text area.
Here i'm assuming that you have a variable in your PHP file with name **$imo_desc_site**, and the text that you want to add in your textarea, is stored in that ($imo_desc_site) variable.
Now to add that text to your textarea, **you just have to echo that text between opening and closing tag of your textarea.**

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imo_desc_site" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">DESCRIÇÃO DO IMÓVEL - EM BREVE</label>
        <textarea readonly rows="15" class="form-control no-resize" style="border: 1px solid #7777774a; border-radius: 10px;">
            <?php echo $imo_desc_site; ?>
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**echo statement** in **PHP** is used to show output on HTML page.